# Show that $H_I^1(R)=0$ if and only if $I$ is not contained in an associated prime of any principal ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain and $I\neq 0$ an ideal. Show that $H_I^1(R)=0$ if and only if $I$ is not contained in an associated prime of any principal ideal.

**Proof:**
$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $H^1_I(R)=0$. Previously, I have shown that $H_I^1(R)\simeq S/R$, where $S=\bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} I^{-i}$ is a subring of $K$ containing $R$ and $I^{-i}=R\underset{K}{:} I^i$. This implies
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    S = R 
    & \Rightarrow
    R = \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} I^{-i}
    \Rightarrow
    R = \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} R \underset{K}{:} I^i
    \Rightarrow
    R = {\{x\in K | Ix\subset R\}}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

At this point I suppose there is something that will imply that $I$ is not contained in an associated prime of any principal ideal. But what? I think what it giving me a hard time is that I do not understand why "$I$ is not contained in an associated prime of any principal ideal" is related to the cohomology?

Comment: This is very easy: if $I$ is contained in an associated prime ideal of a principal ideal, say $bR$, then there $a\in R\setminus bR$ such that $Ia\subseteq bR$. Then $Ix\subseteq R$, where $x=a/b$, a contradiction.

Comment: Where is the contradiction? Is it because $R=\{x\in K |Ix\subset R\}$

Comment: Moreover, Is this if and only if?

Comment: The contradiction is that you found an element in $I^{-1}$ which is not in $R$.

Comment: Yes, the converse it's also easy.

Comment: However, is not clear to me how you got $R = \bigcup\limits_{i\geq 0} R \underset{K}{:} I^i\Rightarrow R = {\{x\in K | Ix\subset R\}}$. (Not necessary in the proof, but unclear.)